# Difference between System call and System call service routines

Tags: linux, system-calls

I am going through how actually system calls works and learned a term `system call service routine`.
I am confused what is difference between `system call` and `system call service routine` ?

For example, on Linux system `man syscalls` lists all the system calls there is a system call `execve()` to execute a new program specified by pathname. Later I found that it actually calling the system call service routine `sys_execve` (`execve()` has the system call number 11 (__NR_exevce). Thus, in the sys_call_table vector, entry 11 contains the address of `sys_execve()`).

What is  `__NR_exevce` ? Where I can find `sys_call_table vector` ?
I also found that on linux, system call service routines typically have names of the form `sys_xyz()`, where `xyz()` is the system call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

System call is something abstract. It's a *way* of communication between user-space to kernel, by passing specific data to specific registers specific to a platform.

Kernel is a program. Linux Kernel is written in C programming language.

Here, "system call service routine" is the name of the function in C programming language that handles a specific system call.

So user space program calls system call number `__NR_execve`. On x86 architecture, the user space program places the number 59 in eax register and then executes instruction `int 0x80`. Specific system call handling routines are executed in the kernel, which cause the function `sys_execve()` in kernel to be executed.

> What is __NR_exevce ?

A macro in C programming language that provides platform-agnostic access to the system call number associated with `execve` system call. It allows writing portable across all Linux platforms programs written in C programming language that automatically during compilation choose the correct platform specific system call number. On arm `__NR_execve` is 11, but on x86 it is 59, etc.. See https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/docs/+/master/constants/syscalls.md#Cross_arch-Numbers

> Where I can find sys_call_table vector

In the kernel sources. Search for it on elixir. https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/ident/sys_call_table